# Create local host file from docker container usnig a bind-mount

Tags: docker

So I'm really new to docker and I'm currently studying the persistence of files in my host machine which were created inside a container. In particular, I'm playing around with bind-mounts to better understand them.

I would like to create a file inside a docker container and make it available for later use in my host machine. Here is what I've done:

1. `mkdir foo_host && cd foo_host`
2. `docker run -d -w /foo_container -v "$(pwd):/foo_container" ubuntu bash -c "echo bar_text  > /bas_file.txt"`

After that i was expecting to find a new file inside my `foo_host` directory. however, to my surprise it was empty. Anyone could please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

I really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

seems ok to me. I think you just have the final statement wrong;

"echo bar_text > /bas_file.txt" should instead be "echo bar_text > bas_file.txt"